# lucene, or sql fulltext?

Tags: sql, full-text-search, lucene

I want to create a search website to search docs (all kinds of formats including pdf), images, videos, and audio.  I also want to be able to filter my search results based on some criteria like author name, date, etc.

I'm doing this in .NET, so what's the easiest way to get up and running?  SQL fulltext searching seems tempting because I'm familiar with sql, and plus since I want to filter my search results, it will be easy to store the filter fields for each item.

Comment: I also need to get snippets from each search result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your primary concern is getting it up and running quickly and easily, then SQL fulltext search is definitely the way to go.

Lucene.NET has its advantages, but it is by no means a walk in the park to set up correctly.  The documentation is a bit lacking and there are a very limited number of examples on the web.

Comment: thanks...do you know if it's possible to return snippets of search results with sql fulltext search?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But you will need a stored procedure for that. Take a look at this sample:

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure for snippets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SimpleCommentar
  @SearchTerm nvarchar(100),
  @Style nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
  CREATE TABLE #match_docs
  (
    doc_id bigint NOT NULL PRIMA
  );
  INSERT INTO #match_docs
  (
    doc_id
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT
    Commentary_ID
  FROM Commentary
  WHERE FREETEXT 
  (
    Commentary, 
    @SearchTerm, 
    LANGUAGE N'English'
  );
  DECLARE @db_id int = DB_ID(),
    @table_id int = OBJECT_ID(N'
    @column_id int =
    (
      SELECT 
        column_id
      FROM sys.columns
      WHERE object_id = OBJECT_I
        AND name = N'Commentary'
    );
  SELECT
    s.Commentary_ID,
    t.Title,
    MIN
    (
      N'...' + SUBSTRING
      (
        REPLACE
          (
            c.Commentary, 
            s.Display_Term, 
 N'<span style="' + @Style + '">' + s.Display_Term + '</span>'
          ), 
        s.Pos - 512, 
        s.Length + 1024
      ) + N'...'
    ) AS Snippet
  FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT 
        c.Commentary_ID,
        w.Display_Term,
        PATINDEX
          (
            N'%[^a-z]' + w.Display_Term + N'[^a-z]%', 
            c.Commentary
          ) AS Pos, 
        LEN(w.Display_Term) AS Length
      FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document
        (
          @db_id, 
          @table_id
        ) w
      INNER JOIN dbo.Commentary c
        ON w.document_id = c.Commentary_ID
      WHERE w.column_id = @column_id
        AND EXISTS 
          (
            SELECT 1
            FROM #match_docs m
            WHERE m.doc_id = w.document_id 
          )
        AND EXISTS 
          (
            SELECT 1
            FROM sys.dm_fts_parser
              (
                N'FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "' + @SearchTerm + N'")', 
                1033, 
                0, 
                1
              ) p
            WHERE p.Display_Term = w.Display_Term
          )
    ) s
  INNER JOIN dbo.Commentary c
    ON s.Commentary_ID = c.Commentary_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Book_Commentary bc
    ON c.Commentary_ID = bc.Commentary_ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Book_Title bt
    ON bc.Book_ID = bt.Book_ID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Title t
    ON bt.Title_ID = t.Title_ID
  WHERE t.Is_Primary_Title = 1
  GROUP BY
    s.Commentary_ID,
    t.Title;
  DROP TABLE #match_docs;
END;
```